# Prevent apt-get remove from uninstalling related packages

Tags: apt, uninstall

I uninstalled some packages with `apt-get remove`. In addition to the selected packages the `Okular` document viewer was removed, which was running on my computer long before the other packages. Is there any way to prevent those "side effects", so that I don't have to reinstall programms again?

Comment: You could use `dpkg -r [packagename]` to remove only the package files, instead of apt-get. However, this is not usually what you want, because you will end up with unused files (`apt-get autoremove` will remove these for you).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okular depended on some or all of the packages your removed. That's why it was removed too. When you install a program, its dependencies must be installed at the same time, if you remove a dependency, the parent program is removed too.

> Programs often use some of the same files as each other. Rather than putting these files into each package, a separate package can be installed to provide them for all of the programs that need them. So, to install a program which needs one of these files, the package containing those files must also be installed. When a package depends on another in this way, it is known as a package dependency. By specifying dependencies, packages can be made smaller and simpler, and duplicates of files and programs are mostly removed.
>
> When you install a program, its dependencies must be installed at the same time. Usually, most of the required dependencies will already be installed, but a few extras may be needed, too. So, when you install a package, don't be surprised if several other packages are installed too - these are just dependencies which are needed for your chosen package to function properly.

Source: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingSoftware